# Connect to MSSQL database with period in the name, using ODBC

Tags: sql-server, ruby, sql-server-2008, odbc, rubymine

If I have a database named something like "foo4.3" and I attempt to connect to it using odbc it looks for a database named "foo4". The period works fine in any other string (for instance puts "foo4.3" outputs "foo4.3" so I'm a little confused as to why it is attempting to look for a database named "foo4". I've already tried the literal string version (single quotes) as well as the escape enabled string (double quotes) and attempted to escape the period but I get the same results.

Comment: I'm not sure about your case but most databases don't allow dots in database names.

Comment: What RDBMS? Are you open to using a library like Sequel to connect to your DB?

Comment: @dgasper We're using SQL 05 and 08 and are able to use periods.

Comment: @Phrogz are you asking about the gem we're using to connect to our db?

Comment: "SQL05 and 08" == Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the database name in brackets: `[foo4.3]`